# Updating One VO when other VO creates a row

Tags: oracle-adf

I have 2 View objects :
1- ViewObject1 - Based on entity1 and entity2.
2- ViewObject2 - Based on entity1

Scenario:

I am creating a new row in entity1 using ViewObject2.

Expectation:
I want that the ViewObject1 should also have a newly created row as both are based on entity1.

Answer (score 0):

You should try re-querying ViewObject1, after commit.

Comment: i wish to use the record before the commit

Comment: Then, you do dbTransaction.postChanges() instead of commit, then query.

Comment: To add more sense to the scenario : I have a page with a table and a form area . The table gets data using ViewObject1 and form area using ViewObject2 . My requirement is that as soon as the ViewObject2 creates a new row , the same should be shown in the table only (even though it is BLANK)

Comment: try not to ignore my above comment. That’s your solution.